# Generating lists of numbers which sum to points on a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, model

In short, I would like to take a number, say N, and generate a list of n numbers which will sum to N with the constraint is that N itself is a number from a nearly normal distribution with, say $\mu \pm 4\sigma$ for some $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

The way I have been going about this is to build a list for each number N (which was generated on the nearly normal distribution) but am wondering if I don't need to do this. That instead of generating a number N and building an exact list, I could build lists in which each sum to N on a nearly normal distribution?

So basically the lists (which have minimum and maximum values) have to sum to numbers, the totality of which constitute a nearly normal distribution.

I will have k lists, each with m numbers of questions in which, in each list the numbers can range from 0 to r. There is varying number of samples, though at least 100.

More in depth with an example.

Say a list is made of 20 questions, each of which can have a value from 0 to 4. I want to generate data points (such as N on the larger normal distribution) in between the values of  0 and 80 (as 0 * 20 = 0 and 4 * 20 = 80).

Now one way would be to try to divide each N and divide the numbers up over the 20 questions. So for example, say I generate three data points between 0 and 80: $Val1 = 32$, $Val2 = 44$, and $Val3 = 7$, then for each of these three points I would three lists of 20 values between 0 and 4 say:

For $Val1$, $32 = \sum([3,2,0,1,1,4, ... , 3])$

For $Val2$, $44 = \sum([2,3,2,3,1,4, ... , 2])$

For $Val3$, $7  = \sum([1,0,0,0,1,0, ... , 0])$

Again, maybe I don't even have to generate numbers on a normal distribution and divide each over individual lists to get the result of having many lists, each of which sum to a number on a larger normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks for showing some of the things you tried. But in the midst of that discussion, I get lost at several points. (a) If you have min and max restrictions, then technically you can't have a normal distribution because a normal distribution extends to $\pm \infty$ even though almost all of its probability is in, say $\mu \pm 4\sigma.$ (b) How many 'lists' and how many elements in each list? (c) How large should the overall normal sample be? (d) Do you have a target $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for the overall normal distribution?

Comment: Here is a simulation expt for you to consider. Suppose I want 25 normally distributed numbers with mean 80 and total 2000. Then in R: `set.seed(618); x.tmp = rnorm(25, 80, 4); x = 80*x.tmp/mean(x.tmp)` Then `mean(x)` returns 80 and `sum(x)` returns 2000, as required.

Comment: Now if I take those 25 numbers, how would I generate a list of Scores for each? I posted an answer to the question in which I can do this with Python's version of R's rnorm() function. The lists don't always sum up to N, just on average. If I were to just take the sums of each of the lists that I am generating, should they be a true normal distribution? I would think so as the lists on average sum to each N which was taken from a normal distribution. Though graphing the curve might look like it does, I am curious to as if it is really skewed in some small way.

Comment: Although I cannot tell what you're trying to do, your example looks remarkably like what is requested at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129789, which has a simple, efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

The code below gives a solution to the problem in which each of the lists, such as those as $Val1, Val2, ...$ are generated statistically in that the sum of list elements for each generated N will not always (or usually) sum to the exact number. They however will do so on average and is done through the function: np.random.normal(Score_Mean, Score_Sigma, NumberQuestions).

The code is compatible with Python 3.7. Similar to the program R's rnorm(...) function Python has the function:  np.random.normal(...) which takes the general parameters such as the mean and standard deviation, but also the number of list elements you would like the generated number normally distributed over.

```
import numpy as np

NumberQuestions = 20
NumberofSubjects = 5
Score_Sigma = 1
All_Scores_List = []

Scores = np.random.normal(40, 10, NumberofSubjects)

for Score in Scores :
    Score_Mean = Score/NumberQuestions
    # Use the mean score (Score_Mean) to populate another list which on AVERAGE would average to Score_Mean
    Score_List = np.random.normal(Score_Mean, Score_Sigma, NumberQuestions)
    All_Scores_List.append((np.round(Score_List)).astype(int))

print(Scores)
print(All_Scores_List)
```